# requirements.txt と setuptools の install_requires は、どちらを使うべきですか

Tags: python

Python のパッケージを配布する際、依存するパッケージを指定するのに `requirements.txt` と、 `setuptools` の `install_requires` オプションを利用する方法の二種類があります。
どちらの方法がより一般的で推奨されているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 13, accepted):

setuptoolsの`install_requires`を使うべきです。

`requirements.txt`と`install_requires`では現時点では目的が異なっています。setup.pyに指定したinstall_requiresはパッケージ化の際にメタデータとしてパッケージに同梱されます。
`requirements.txt`を同梱してもそのような動作にはなりません。そのため、利用者が`pip install hogehoge`としてそのパッケージをインストールしたときに正しく依存パッケージをインストールできるのは `install_requires`を設定した場合です。また、メタデータはPythonのPEP345やPEP426でフォーマットと項目が規定されている標準仕様です。

`requirements.txt`は`Requirementsフォーマット`と呼ばれる形式でインストールするパッケージを列挙します。このフォーマットにはpipのオプション(`-f`や`-r`)などを含むことが出来ます。Requirementsフォーマットで記述されたrequirements.txtが将来PEPで標準化される可能性はありますが、現時点では標準化されていません。とはいえ現時点でも、様々なサービスがrequirements.txtをデファクトスタンダードと認めているためか、テスト環境の構築時などにこのファイルを認識して利用してくれます。

パッケージングという観点でいえば、`setuptools`の`install_requires`を利用するべきでしょう。
そのパッケージ自体の開発環境やテスト環境の構築という観点でいえば、`requirements.txt`を動作保証するバージョン指定付きで（一般的には`pip freeze > requirements.txt`で作成して）リポジトリに同梱することが推奨されます。

Comment: 標準化されているか否かについてはご指摘のとおりです。
ただ、`setup.py` の `install_requires` から使う[方法](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool) は確立されています。
また、`install_requires` が抽象依存(abstract dependency)と具象依存(concrete dependency)を[うまくモデル化できていない問題](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/)が指摘されています。

Comment: 問題は、今どう書けば将来に渡って一番はまりが少ないか、ということでしょう。技巧的な「こうすれば動く」は将来負債になります。

少なくとも `pip freeze >requirements.txt` したファイルをsetup.pyの `install_requries` につかうべきではなく、その [方法](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool)で公開されたパッケージは、全ての依存パッケージのバージョンを固定してしまいます。また、 `pip.req.parse_requirements` はドキュメントに定義されたAPIではなく、ある日突然利用者の環境で使えなくなる可能性があります。

私は、将来的にはinstall_requiresはobsoleteになって、
[PEP426 Semantic dependencies](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#semantic-dependencies)に従って記述する方法に切り替わると思いますが、このPEPはまだdraftで、いつどうなっていくのかは何とも言えないところです。

Comment: pipはインストーラであって配布パッケージの作成には一切関わりがありません。
パッケージング生成については、setuptoolsの範囲であり、wheelやmetadata2.0に関する議論もまだ残っています。
今後の変更があることを考えると、小手先のテクニックで回避する方法は控えたほうがよいと思います。
また、requirements.txtとsetup.pyのinstall_requiresのように役割が違うものについて、新しい古いなどという議論はやめてください。

Comment: 今後変更の余地があるのは`setuptools`も同様です。また、`pip freeze`で自動的に生成した`requirements.txt`をそのまま使う前提であれば、手作業でごりごり書いた`instrall_requires`より精度が低いのは当たり前かと思います。現状でバージョンの指定の柔軟性と抽象依存と具象依存の関係を簡単に記述できるという長所を兼ね備えているのは`requirements.txt`であり、`pip`が標準に取り込まれた今、小手先のテクニックと断じるのはどんなものでしょうか。

Comment: 単に開発者の環境をダンプする pip freezeで自動的に生成したrequirements.txtをそのまま使う前提であれば、意図を持って書かれたinstall_requiresと比べて精度が低いことは当たり前と思います。

Answer (score 7):

パッケージを配布する場合に、 pip freeze が出力する requirements をそのまま利用してはいけません。
理由は以下のとおりです。

- テスト自動化やスタイルチェックなど、開発時に使う、そのパッケージが実際には依存していないパッケージまで含まれてしまう可能性がある。
- マイクロバージョンまで詳細に指定されてしまい、複数のパッケージが同じパッケージのバージョン違いに依存するという dependency hell を引き起こす。

Python の有名なライブラリは、マイクロバージョンでは互換性を壊さない用に注意されているので、自分が作成したパッケージを配布するときには setup.py の install_requirements でのバージョン指定をしないか、緩くすることで、 dependency hell　を避ける事ができます。

pip freeze は、 Web アプリケーションをデプロイするときなど、開発環境で検証された構成と同じ構成をステージング・本番環境で作りたい場合などに有効です。

Answer (score 5):

これから先、Python2.7あるいは3.4以上で動作すれば良いという状況であればpipの`requirements.txt`を使うべきです。

`requirements.txt`の特徴として、以下の点が挙げられます。

- 公式パッケージ配布サイト[PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)に登録されていないパッケージへの依存も、URLを書くことにより記述できる
- そのため、TravisCIなどの近年出てきたサービスは`requirements.txt`を前提としている
- 標準に取り込まれた 参考: [Python3.4からpipが標準インストーラに！？](http://qiita.com/ksato9700/items/c5a6db9d17ad0770a747)
- `pip`パッケージを利用すれば、`setup.py`から読みだして使うことができる 参考: [How can I reference requirements.txt for the install_requires kwarg in setuptools' setup.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool)

もし古いPythonで`pip`がインストールされていない環境でも利用したい、かつ、PyPIに登録されているパッケージだけで良い、ということであれば、`install_require`を利用するほうが良いでしょう。

追記: pipとsetuptoolsも含めた詳しい比較のページがあります（英語ですが） 参考: [Concepts & Analyses](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/technical.html#requirements-files-vs-setup-py)